# Rails: Undefined Method Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, methods, undefined

Currently getting an undefined method and I am unsure how to fix this issue, been stuck on this for a while now. All help is much appreciated!

```
NoMethodError in Users#show

undefined method `comments' for nil:NilClass

Extracted source (around line #2):

1: <div class="CommentField">
2: <%= form_for ([@micropost, @micopost.comments.new]) do |f| %>
3: <%= f.text_area :content, :class => "CommentText", :placeholder => "Write a Comment..." %>
4: <div class="CommentButtonContainer">
5: <%= f.submit "Comment",
```

**User Controller**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @school = School.find(params[:id])
    @micropost = Micropost.new
    @comment = Comment.new
    @comment = @micropost.comments.build(params[:comment])
    @microposts = @user.microposts.paginate(:per_page => 10, :page => params[:page])
  end
end
```

**Comment Controller**

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController 
  def create
    @micropost = Micropost.find(params[:micropost_id])
    @comment = @micropost.comments.build(params[:comment])
    @comment.user_id = current_user.id
    @comment.save 
      respond_to do |format|
      format.html 
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

**Comment Form**

```
<div class="CommentField">
<%= form_for ([@micropost, @micopost.comments.new]) do |f| %>
<%= f.text_area :content, :class => "CommentText", :placeholder => "Write a Comment..." %>
<div class="CommentButtonContainer">
<%= f.submit "Comment", :class => "CommentButton b1" %>
</div>
<% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hate to tell you this but you have a typo. You typed `@micopost.comments.new` instead of `@micropost.comments.new`. Correct that and it'll fix this problem.

Comment: godammit stupid move on mybehalf, thank you